# How to cast C#'s linq WHERE statement?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class Literal and a Tag is inheriting from it.

I would like to do the following but I am getting

```
Unable to cast object of type 'WhereListIterator`1[Core.Literal]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Core.Tag]'.

 private List<Literal> literals;
public List<Tag> Tags
        {
            get { return (List<Tag>)literals.Where(x => x is Tag); }
        }
```

thanks

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You would be better off doing:

```
literals.OfType<Tag>().ToList();
```

This gives you a `List<Tag>`.

You can also do:

```
var asList = new List<Tag>(literals.OfType<Tag>());
```

Casting simply does not work because LINQ works in terms of either `IEnumerable<T>` or `IQueryable<T>` which neither use List as a backing implementation for the results. The second method I posted uses a constructor overload of `List<T>` the takes in an `IEnumerable<T>` as its initial collection of objects.  Also in this scenario the `OfType<T>` method from LINQ is a much cleaner, shorter form of essentially filtering a list with `Where(x -> x is T)`.

Also, `OfType<T>` in this scenario is a much better idea, because the result is an `IEnumerable<T>` of your target type.  `Where(x => x is T)` will return an `IEnumerable<T>` of the original source's type.  So that's why `(List<Tag>)literals.Where(x => x is Tag).ToList()` emit an error for invalid casts.

More information on [ToList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx)

More information on [OfType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

```
literals.Select(x => x as Tag).Where(x => x != null).ToList()
```

Note that this will return new list. You won't be able to do where and modify original list by this. Also this can be done like this: `literals.OfType<Tag>().ToList()` and it will return `IList<Tag>`

Update: modified type

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Tag>)literals.Where(x => x is Tag).ToList();
```

or even better :

```
literals.OfType<Tag>();
```

then you can create a new list from it:

```
new List<Tag>(literals.OfType<Tag>());
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the effect you want you could do this:

```
public List<Tag> Tags
{
    get { return literals.Where(x => x is Tag).ToList(); }
}
```

Do realize that this is not a cast but the creation of a list!

Answer (score 0):

How about adding ToList()?

Your getter becomes: `literals.Where(x => x is Tag).ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
literals.Where(x => x is Tag).Cast<Tag>().ToList();
```

it works if `Tag` is derived from `Literal`

Comment: And you may also replace Where() statement with OfType<Tag>

Answer (score 0):

The `Where` method returns the same type as the source, so you would have to cast each item, then use the `ToList` method to create a list from the result:

```
return literals.Where(x => x is Tag).Select(x => (Tag)x).ToList();
```

You can also us the `OfType` method:

```
return literals.OfType<Tag>().ToList();
```